# execute javascript function onkeydown

Tags: javascript, html, function, keyboard

I am looking for a way to execute a javascript function when a specific key is pressed, for example pressing the down key will result in `function down()` and the left key will execute `function left()`. Is this possible preferably with javascript? I could use jquery, but I prefer javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 40) {
        down();
    } else if(e.keyCode === 38) {
        up();
    }
},false);
```

Comment: so is `down()` another function?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming you already had it. But it doesn't have to be, you can do whatever you want to do right inside the conditionals, instead of calling `up()` or `down()`.

Comment: ok, thanks, sorry but I'm a beginner at javascript

Answer (score 1):

bfavaretto's answer is good, but it won't support all the browsers. Try this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if(keycode == 37) 
        left();
    if(keycode == 39) 
        right();
    if(keycode == 38) 
        up();
    if(keycode == 40) 
        down();
});
```